# Get service names depending on server name

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I'm writing a simple PowerShell script to get the status of services from local and remote servers. I'm reading in the the servers and services from an XML file I created:

```xml
<Settings>
  <Server>
    <Name>Server1</Name>
    <StartOrder>1</StartOrder>
    <Services>
      <Service>
        <Name>Service1</Name>
        <StartOrder>1</StartOrder>
      </Service>
      <Service>
       <Name>Service2</Name>
       <StartOrder>2</StartOrder>
      </Service>
    </Services>
  </Server>
</Settings>
```

Here's my code:

```psh
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $args)

function readServersfromXML() {
    $xml.Settings.Server | select -ExpandProperty Name
}

function readServerServicesfromXML($server) {
    $server
    $xml.Settings.Server.Services.Service | Where {$_ -eq $server}
}

function getServiceStatus($server, $service) {
    Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server
}

$servers = ( readServersfromXML )
#loop through the configxml and get status of services
foreach ( $server in $servers ) {
    $services = ( readServerServicesfromXML $server )
    foreach ( $service in $services ) {
        getServiceStatus $server $service
    }
}
```

What works is the `$servers` hash is getting populated, but the `$services` hash is not and I have no idea why. My assumption is that the `readServerServicesfromXML()` function isn't finding the path, but I have no idea why. Can someone point me in the correct direction, or offer a better way to do this? Eventually I'll be using this script to remotely start services in a particular order as dictated by the XML file (hence the `startOrder` XML tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slight modifications your code runs fine:

`readServerServicesfromXML` function:

```
function readServerServicesfromXML ( $server ) {
    $xml.Settings.Server |
        Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $server} |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Services
}
```

Nested foreach loop:

```
foreach ( $service in $services.ChildNodes ) {
    getServiceStatus $server $service.Name
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I'm surprised that I wasn't too far from the solution I was looking for. Thank you beatcracker for the tweak to my code.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $xml.Settings.Server.Services.Service | Where {$_ -eq $server}
> ```

A `<Service>` node is never equal to a server name, so this expression always evaluates to `$null`. Because of that, the function only returns a list of the server names (output of the `$server` statement before the above line).

Use a conditional XPath expression for selecting nodes based on the value of another node:

```
function readServerServicesfromXML ($server) {
    $xml.SelectNodes("/Settings/Server[Name='$server']/Services/Service") |
        Select-Object -Expand Name
}
```